# CSS doesn't shows when load a component

Tags: css, reactjs, mapbox

I'm working with mapbox and my problem is that it doesn't shows me the map as should be.

If I load the component in render directly (example 1) it works and shows the map perfectly but if I load the component when change the state (example 2) doesn't shows me well.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="NavBar">
                <NavbarComponent parentNavbar={this.doParentNavbar} />
            </div>
            <div className="Map">
                <MapComponent />
            </div>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Example 2

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="NavBar">
                <NavbarComponent parentNavbar={this.doParentNavbar} />
            </div>
            <div className="Map">
                { 
                    (this.state.nameMap) ? <MapComponent /> : null
                }
            </div>
      </div>
    );
}
```

CSS File:

```
.NavBar {
  position: relative !important;
  z-index: 9999 !important;
}

.Map {
  position: absolute !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  overflow: visible !important;
  z-index: -9999 !important;
}

.mapboxgl-canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: `{this.state.nameMap ? <MapComponent /> : "" }` Can you try this?

Comment: `{this.state.nameMap && <MapComponent /> }`  try this and i believe your state.nameMap is empty.

Comment: I've tried both but is something wrong in css... canvas get the height and width from navbar, I dont know why

Comment: What type is `state.nameMap` ? I expect it's a string, if it is then `{ this.state.nameMap && <MapComponent /> }` will not work since a boolean is required to pefrom this, the same goes with the ternary operator.

Comment: it doesnt work :( Can I put here an url of the project on github??

Comment: here is the project... please help me. I dont know where is the problem https://github.com/jadelmag/mapboxdesigner

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I'm so stupid....

In App.css I forgot this:

```
body {
   height: 100vh;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   font-family: sans-serif;
}
```